# /boot has run out of room and cannot be resized

Tags: boot, partitioning, resize

I recognize this answer has been provided multiple times, but I guess I need a little more help than what I have read thus far.
I have a hardware RAID1 SSD set (AMD RAID) that I set up successfully on my ASUS (M4A785-M) motherboard. As per my previous post, I cloned my previous hard drive RAID1 set to the SSDs using Clonezilla. I had a few issues, but the migration was successful.

I just got a notification for an update to Ubuntu base. I tried the update but there was not enough space. I have deleted all older version and memtest and it still needs 697K more space. I have never had an issue before that couldn't be solved just by getting rid of older versions, but it appears more space is needed for this newer base version.

I tried to resize using a GParted startup disk, but have had no success. It appears that I cannot extend this partition. I thought I read somewhere that one could move the `/boot` partition to an unallocated partition and use that as a the new boot partition. If that is the case, I would appreciate knowing exactly how to do that.
If that is not the case, I have two mirrored SSDs with a working Ubuntu operating system that cannot be upgraded.

Any advice on how I can resolve this problem without having to reinstall everything I have from scratch would be appreciated. I have included my GParted output. As you can see, I have plenty of unallocated space on the drive.

[image: My Gparted output]

Comment: Try creating a directory /boot2 place your files in that and soft link them into /boot. `ln -s /boot2/any_file /boot/any_file`

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Would I have to link all new Ubuntu versions that same way. Get the update into /boot and copy them over to /boot2 and do the link to keep ample space in /boot open?

Comment: yes. This may not work, but your next solution is probably back everything up, erase your partitions and start again

Comment: Manual, temporary solution: APT keeps two kernels installed. When you have checked the newest installed one works correctly, manually remove the older one. This should give you the space to install another.

Comment: I have to admit that I am more than a little nervous to try this out. I think I do need to start from scratch. I have never done an entire system backup so I need to research how to do this so I don't need to reinstall my many apps or lose any user data. . Thank you all for trying to help me with the solution I requested but I see now this is really a bandaid solution and I need to take a deeper dive and fix this once and for all.

Comment: Ok, so I backed up my entire system using APTIK, wiped out my RAID1 pair and installed the latest LTS Ubuntu 18.04 version. Then I did a restore. Had to do a little tweaking here and there (a lot actually) to get it back to the same as it was prior to the reinstall but I got there, all in one day.I notice that now there is only one big partition for the entire file system so space for /boot will no longer be a concern. Thanks to all who gave me advice here. I think this was the most comprehensive solution I could do to resolve this issue.

Comment: @user3147955 You could post your latest comment as an answer. [Self-answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

1
Ok, so I backed up my entire system using APTIK, wiped out my RAID1 pair and installed the latest LTS Ubuntu 18.04 version. Then I did a restore. Had to do a little tweaking here and there (a lot actually) to get it back to the same as it was prior to the reinstall but I got there, all in one day.I notice that now there is only one big partition for the entire file system so space for /boot will no longer be a concern. Thanks to all who gave me advice here. I think this was the most comprehensive solution I could do to resolve this issue. –